# Custom function to matrix columns pairs

Tags: r

Good afternoon ,

Assume we have the following matrix :

```
> dput(tnn)
structure(c(1L, 19L, 5L, 6L, 10L, 2L, 4L, 7L, 12L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 
8L, 13L, 1L, 4L, 15L, 16L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 14L, 1L, 15L, 5L, 
6L, 14L, 1L, 15L, 7L, 2L, 9L, 17L, 4L, 8L, 3L, 9L, 18L, 4L, 9L, 
10L, 11L, 4L, 7L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 1L, 15L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 1L, 15L, 
12L, 2L, 14L, 17L, 4L, 13L, 3L, 14L, 18L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 14L, 4L, 
12L, 4L, 15L, 16L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 15L, 16L, 5L, 6L, 17L, 7L, 12L, 
19L, 2L, 18L, 8L, 13L, 19L, 3L, 1L, 19L, 9L, 14L, 17L), .Dim = c(5L, 
19L))

> tnn
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12] [,13] [,14] [,15] [,16] [,17] [,18]
[1,]    1    2    3    4    5    5    7    8    9     9     9    12    13     5     4     4    17    18
[2,]   19    4    4   15    6    6    2    3   10    10    10     2     3     6    15    15     7     8
[3,]    5    7    8   16   14   14    9    9   11    11    11    14    14    14    16    16    12    13
[4,]    6   12   13    2    1    1   17   18    4     1     1    17    18     4     5     5    19    19
[5,]   10    1    1    3   15   15    4    4    7    15    15     4     4    12     6     6     2     3
     [,19]
[1,]     1
[2,]    19
[3,]     9
[4,]    14
[5,]    17
```

I'm wanting to calculate the length of intersection for each pairs of columns. For example :

```
> intersect(tnn[,1],tnn[,19])
[1]  1 19
> length(intersect(tnn[,1],tnn[,19]))
[1] 2
```

For this , I tried :

```
custom_fun<-function(data,x,y){
return(length(intersect(data[,x],data[,y])))
}
outer(1:ncol(tnn),1:ncol(tnn),function(tnn,x,y) custom_fun(tnn,x,y))
```

But I got the following error :

```
Error in data[, x] : incorrect number of dimensions
```

Thank you for help !

Comment: So what will be your output format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `outer` expects a binary function. I’m assuming this was a typo in your code.
2. `outer` treats the function passed to it as *vectorised*. Your function isn’t (because `intersection` isn’t). But you can vectorise it using `mapply`:

   ```
   cols = seq_len(ncol(tnn))
   outer(cols, cols, function (x, y) mapply(custom_fun, list(tnn), x, y))
   ```

Comment: Yes this is exactly what i'm looking for ! But I have question : I know that mapply is used with 3 arguments. What this the meaning of : mapply(custom, list(tnn), 1, 19) ?

Comment: Normally mapply is used like : mapply(function , vec1 , vec2 )

Comment: `mapply` can be used with an arbitrary number of arguments, not just three. It tries to treat all arguments except the first as vectors of the same size, and iterates over them in parallel. The `list(…)` prevents the first argument from being treated as a vector of size > 1. Instead, `mapply` now sees a list of size 1, so it *recycles* the only item inside that list and passes it, unmodified, to ever call of `custom_fun`.

Answer (score 2):

We can use `combn` lie below

```
unlist(
  combn(data.frame(tnn),
    2,
    FUN = function(...) setNames(length(do.call(intersect, unname(...))), toString(names(...))),
    simplify = FALSE
  )
)
```

which gives named result indicating the combinations of two columns

```
 V1, V2   V1, V3   V1, V4   V1, V5   V1, V6   V1, V7   V1, V8   V1, V9 
       1        1        0        3        3        0        0        1
 V1, V10  V1, V11  V1, V12  V1, V13  V1, V14  V1, V15  V1, V16  V1, V17
       2        2        0        0        2        2        2        1
 V1, V18  V1, V19   V2, V3   V2, V4   V2, V5   V2, V6   V2, V7   V2, V8
       1        2        2        2        1        1        3        1 
  V2, V9  V2, V10  V2, V11  V2, V12  V2, V13  V2, V14  V2, V15  V2, V16
       2        1        1        3        1        2        1        1
 V2, V17  V2, V18  V2, V19   V3, V4   V3, V5   V3, V6   V3, V7   V3, V8
       3        0        1        2        1        1        1        3
  V3, V9  V3, V10  V3, V11  V3, V12  V3, V13  V3, V14  V3, V15  V3, V16
       1        1        1        1        3        1        1        1
 V3, V17  V3, V18  V3, V19   V4, V5   V4, V6   V4, V7   V4, V8   V4, V9
       0        3        1        1        1        2        2        1
 V4, V10  V4, V11  V4, V12  V4, V13  V4, V14  V4, V15  V4, V16  V4, V17
       1        1        2        2        1        3        3        1
 V4, V18  V4, V19   V5, V6   V5, V7   V5, V8   V5, V9  V5, V10  V5, V11
       1        0        5        0        0        0        2        2
 V5, V12  V5, V13  V5, V14  V5, V15  V5, V16  V5, V17  V5, V18  V5, V19
       1        1        3        3        3        0        0        2
  V6, V7   V6, V8   V6, V9  V6, V10  V6, V11  V6, V12  V6, V13  V6, V14
       0        0        0        2        2        1        1        3
 V6, V15  V6, V16  V6, V17  V6, V18  V6, V19   V7, V8   V7, V9  V7, V10
       3        3        0        0        2        2        3        1
 V7, V11  V7, V12  V7, V13  V7, V14  V7, V15  V7, V16  V7, V17  V7, V18
       1        3        1        1        1        1        3        0
 V7, V19   V8, V9  V8, V10  V8, V11  V8, V12  V8, V13  V8, V14  V8, V15
       2        2        1        1        1        3        1        1
 V8, V16  V8, V17  V8, V18  V8, V19  V9, V10  V9, V11  V9, V12  V9, V13
       1        0        3        1        3        3        1        1
 V9, V14  V9, V15  V9, V16  V9, V17  V9, V18  V9, V19 V10, V11 V10, V12
       1        1        1        1        0        1        5        0
V10, V13 V10, V14 V10, V15 V10, V16 V10, V17 V10, V18 V10, V19 V11, V12
       0        0        1        1        0        0        2        0 
V11, V13 V11, V14 V11, V15 V11, V16 V11, V17 V11, V18 V11, V19 V12, V13
       0        0        1        1        0        0        2        2
V12, V14 V12, V15 V12, V16 V12, V17 V12, V18 V12, V19 V13, V14 V13, V15
       3        1        1        3        0        2        2        1
V13, V16 V13, V17 V13, V18 V13, V19 V14, V15 V14, V16 V14, V17 V14, V18
       1        0        3        1        3        3        1        0
V14, V19 V15, V16 V15, V17 V15, V18 V15, V19 V16, V17 V16, V18 V16, V19
       1        5        0        0        0        0        0        0
V17, V18 V17, V19 V18, V19
       1        2        1
```

Answer (score 1):

tidyverse approach

```r
tnn <- structure(c(1L, 19L, 5L, 6L, 10L, 2L, 4L, 7L, 12L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 
                   8L, 13L, 1L, 4L, 15L, 16L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 14L, 1L, 15L, 5L, 
                   6L, 14L, 1L, 15L, 7L, 2L, 9L, 17L, 4L, 8L, 3L, 9L, 18L, 4L, 9L, 
                   10L, 11L, 4L, 7L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 1L, 15L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 1L, 15L, 
                   12L, 2L, 14L, 17L, 4L, 13L, 3L, 14L, 18L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 14L, 4L, 
                   12L, 4L, 15L, 16L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 15L, 16L, 5L, 6L, 17L, 7L, 12L, 
                   19L, 2L, 18L, 8L, 13L, 19L, 3L, 1L, 19L, 9L, 14L, 17L), .Dim = c(5L, 
                                                                                    19L))
library(tidyverse)

expand.grid(seq_len(ncol(tnn)), seq_len(ncol(tnn))) %>% as.data.frame() %>%
  mutate(des_len = map2_int(Var1, Var2, ~length(intersect(tnn[,.x], tnn[, .y]))))
#>     Var1 Var2 des_len
#> 1      1    1       5
#> 2      2    1       1
#> 3      3    1       1
#> 4      4    1       0
#> 5      5    1       3
#> 6      6    1       3
....
```

Instead of having permutations, if you want to have combinations, you may do something like this

```
combn(seq_len(ncol(tnn)), 2) %>% t %>% as.data.frame() %>%
  mutate(des_len = map2_int(V1, V2, ~length(intersect(tnn[,.x], tnn[,.y]))))
```

Comment: When using the tidyverse you could use `tidyr::expand` instead of `expand.grid`.

Comment: Sure @KonradRudolph, thanks for info.  I will keep that in mind, next time.  :)

Comment: Normally i usually try to avoid expand.grid for large number of columns / rows. This function creates combinations of integers. After that , we loop over pairs using apply !

Comment: @TouMou, see revised answer, I added strategy for having combinations only instead of having permutations.

Comment: Yes combn(seq_len(ncol(tnn)), 2)  is better !

Answer (score 0):

Another option using genfilter :

```
library(data.table)
library(genefilter)


tnn=structure(c(1L, 19L, 5L, 6L, 10L, 2L, 4L, 7L, 12L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 
8L, 13L, 1L, 4L, 15L, 16L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 14L, 1L, 15L, 5L, 
6L, 14L, 1L, 15L, 7L, 2L, 9L, 17L, 4L, 8L, 3L, 9L, 18L, 4L, 9L, 
10L, 11L, 4L, 7L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 1L, 15L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 1L, 15L, 
12L, 2L, 14L, 17L, 4L, 13L, 3L, 14L, 18L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 14L, 4L, 
12L, 4L, 15L, 16L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 15L, 16L, 5L, 6L, 17L, 7L, 12L, 
19L, 2L, 18L, 8L, 13L, 19L, 3L, 1L, 19L, 9L, 14L, 17L), .Dim = c(5L, 
19L))


custom_fun<-function(x,y){
return(length(intersect(x,y)))
}

dist2(as.matrix(tnn),custom_fun,diagonal = 0)

      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12] [,13]
 [1,]    0    1    1    0    3    3    0    0    1     2     2     0     0
 [2,]    1    0    2    2    1    1    3    1    2     1     1     3     1
 [3,]    1    2    0    2    1    1    1    3    1     1     1     1     3
 [4,]    0    2    2    0    1    1    2    2    1     1     1     2     2
 [5,]    3    1    1    1    0    5    0    0    0     2     2     1     1
 [6,]    3    1    1    1    5    0    0    0    0     2     2     1     1
 [7,]    0    3    1    2    0    0    0    2    3     1     1     3     1
 [8,]    0    1    3    2    0    0    2    0    2     1     1     1     3
 [9,]    1    2    1    1    0    0    3    2    0     3     3     1     1
[10,]    2    1    1    1    2    2    1    1    3     0     5     0     0
[11,]    2    1    1    1    2    2    1    1    3     5     0     0     0
[12,]    0    3    1    2    1    1    3    1    1     0     0     0     2
[13,]    0    1    3    2    1    1    1    3    1     0     0     2     0
[14,]    2    2    1    1    3    3    1    1    1     0     0     3     2
[15,]    2    1    1    3    3    3    1    1    1     1     1     1     1
[16,]    2    1    1    3    3    3    1    1    1     1     1     1     1
[17,]    1    3    0    1    0    0    3    0    1     0     0     3     0
[18,]    1    0    3    1    0    0    0    3    0     0     0     0     3
[19,]    2    1    1    0    2    2    2    1    1     2     2     2     1
      [,14] [,15] [,16] [,17] [,18] [,19]
 [1,]     2     2     2     1     1     2
 [2,]     2     1     1     3     0     1
 [3,]     1     1     1     0     3     1
 [4,]     1     3     3     1     1     0
 [5,]     3     3     3     0     0     2
 [6,]     3     3     3     0     0     2
 [7,]     1     1     1     3     0     2
 [8,]     1     1     1     0     3     1
 [9,]     1     1     1     1     0     1
[10,]     0     1     1     0     0     2
[11,]     0     1     1     0     0     2
[12,]     3     1     1     3     0     2
[13,]     2     1     1     0     3     1
[14,]     0     3     3     1     0     1
[15,]     3     0     5     0     0     0
[16,]     3     5     0     0     0     0
[17,]     1     0     0     0     1     2
[18,]     0     0     0     1     0     1
[19,]     1     0     0     2     1     0
```